# Permission Denied error on R

Tags: r

```
write.csv(mtcars,file='firstexample.csv')
```

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    cannot open the
>   connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append,
>   "a", "w")) :   cannot open file 'firstexample.csv': Permission denied

Comment: Are you sure about the error message?

Comment: Seems like your operating system isn't given your R session permission to that directory. What is your OS? Does your user account have write permissions to whatever directory you're in?

Comment: @Gregor, I am working in Windows 10 machine. I have both RGui and RStudio, Receiving error with RStudio and works fine with RGui.

Comment: It Started working after changing the Working directory for RStudio, still facing Permission Denied error with installing packages in RStudio and not with rGui.

Comment: Since it's an RStudio-specific issue, you'll probably have better luck on the RStudio Support site or RStudio community forums. A hacky fix would be to run RStudio as administrator, but that is also a security risk. You could look at `.libPaths()` in both R and RStudio to see the directories being used for package installation and try to make sure they have the same permissions. Ditto for the directory you're trying to write the CSV to.